# Difference between AWS Snapshot and Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume, snapshot

I see that snapshot is just a backup of volume except that you can create another volume from the snapshot. I guess there would be other differences. Does anyone notice other differences which really matter?

Comment: This is well documented by AWS. What documentation have you read? What parts are confusing? Please show some effort to solve your question. Then come back and ask specific questions from what you learned.

Comment: @Gucci the problem is that it doesn't really make sense to speak of the "difference" between two things that are so fundamentally different from each other.  There is really no situation where the choice of which of these things you need would be ambiguous, so it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the responses, I did my own research. Here is what I found. Snapshots go across regions where volumes stay in the same region as the snapshot. You can create a copy of a snapshot but you can't create a copy of a volume. In order to make a copy of a volume you have to use a snapshot. Volumes, images, instances all depend on the snapshot. Snapshot is the glue between volumes, images and instances. Please add if anyone finds other interesting facts.

Comment: That is a good start. However, approach understanding volumes in the same way that you would look at a disk drive attached to your system except that this disk is network attached. Approach snapshots as optimized incremental backups. You can restore your system from snapshots. You can also create new volumes from snapshots. The two are very different technologies that are complementary to each other.